# Coursera: Parts of a String

Tags: python, string, coursera-api

I'm having a bit of trouble with a Python problem that involves strings.

The prompt is:

> Modify the `first_and_last` function so that it returns `True` if the first letter of the string is the same as the last letter of the string, `False` if they’re different. Remember that you can access characters using `message[0]` or `message[-1]`. Be careful how you handle the empty string, which should return `True` since nothing is equal to nothing.

This is what I have:

```
def first_and_last(message):
  for char in message:
    if char[0] == char[-1]:
      return True
    elif char == " ":
      return True
    else:
      return False

print(first_and_last("else"))
print(first_and_last("tree"))
print(first_and_last(""))
```

And the output I'm receiving:

```
True
True
None
```

Not quite, `first_and_last("tree")` returned `True`, should be
`False`. Have you added the check for empty strings, and used
correct string indexing? Hint: what do the index numbers of
0 and -1 mean for string handling in Python?

Anyone have any idea how to help?

Comment: Hint: When indexing strings, the index numbers `0` and `-1` mean mean the first character and last character respectively of the string.

Answer (score 1):

I'll avoid answering the problem itself and try to give some hints to guide you:

- "What do the index numbers of 0 and -1 mean for string handling in Python?" - well, this was already given to you.
- What is the difference between char and message? What types of objects are both of those? In fact, char[0] and char[-1] seems odd. Shouldn't that cause an exception?
- Programming languages, especially ones like python, are a playground. Printing objects usually helps you understand what's going on. (Try printing each char in the message and see what you get)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'not' and 'or' comparison operators to output the desired result.

```
def first_and_last(message):
    if not message or message[0] == message[-1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Please add a few sentences to explain what your code is doing, so you can get more upvotes for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
def first_and_last(message):
  if not message or message[0] == message[len(message)-1]:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answers on stackoverflow

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
def first_and_last(message):
    if len(message)==0:
        return True
    else:
        return message[0]==message[-1]
```

Comment: Please, use ctr+k to show your codes in a code format.

Answer (score 0):

```
def first_and_last(message):
  if not message or message[0] == message[len(message)-1]:
    return True
  else:
    return False

print(first_and_last("else"))
print(first_and_last("tree"))
print(first_and_last(""))

Here is your output:
True
False
True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def first_and_last(message):
    if len(message)==0 or message[-1]==message[0]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(first_and_last("else"))
print(first_and_last("tree"))
print(first_and_last(""))
```

Here is your output:

```
True
False
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I was getting the same issue with the problem when I was trying to solve it.
Mainly I was getting issue for the null string. If you do not use or operation in your code try using the condition for null string first.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32236366)